# ATTINY84: Weird problem with reversed byte order

Tags: arduino, bit, avr, attiny

I am encoding 6 values (4x 3bit + 1bit) into a 16bit integer and transfer them via serial to an ATTINY84 splitting them into 2 bytes. That works all good until the point that I re-assemble the bytes into a 16bit int.

Example:

I am sending the following binary state `0001110000001100` which translates to `7180` and gets split into a byte array of `[18, 28]`.

I am putting that byte array into the EEPROM and read it on the next power cycle.

After power cycle my serial debug output looks like this:

```
18
28
7180
```

Awesome. Looks all good and my code for that part is:

```
byte d0 = EEPROM.read(0);
byte d1 = EEPROM.read(1);
unsigned int w = d0 + (256 * d1);
```

But now the weirdest thing happens. When I do a bit-by-bit read I am getting back:

```
0011000000111000

should be:

0001110000001100
```

via:

```
 for(byte t = 0; t < 16; t++) {
    serial.print(bitRead(w, t) ? "1" : "0");
  }
```

The bit representation is completely reversed. How is that possible? Or maybe I am missing something.

Also I confirmed when I extract the actual 3 bit location to receive my original value `0..7` it's all off.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also tried with a `union` converter - same output.

Comment: Looks like I fell into the little/big endian trap...

Comment: I think there is no problem, except that you interpret incorrectly your display.. Your serial.print() procedure starts by printing the LSB, then the higher other bits, ie it does a bit reverse in the display.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I fell into the little/big endian trap.

Basically as Alain said, in the comments - everything is correct and it's just the representations.

I came up with the following method that can extract bits from a little endian stored number that needs to be in a big endian format:

```
/**
 * @bex
 */
uint8_t bexd(uint16_t n, uint8_t o, uint8_t l, uint8_t d) {
  uint8_t v = 0;
  uint8_t ob = d - o;
  for (uint8_t b=ob; b > (ob-l); b--) v = ( v << 1 ) | ( 0x0001 & ( n >> (b-1) ) );
  return v;
}
uint8_t bexw(uint16_t n, uint8_t o, uint8_t l) {return bexd(n, o, l, 16);}
uint8_t bexb(uint8_t n, uint8_t o, uint8_t l) {return bexd(n, o, l, 8);}
```

For example:

In big endian the "second" value is stored in bit 3,4, and 5, compared to little endian where it will be stored in bit 10, 11, and 12. The method above allows to work a "little endian" value like it would be an "big endian" value.

To extract the second value from this value `0011000000111000` just do:

```
byte v = bex(7180, 3, 3);  // 111
Serial.println(v); // prints 255
```

Hope that helps someone.